# How to decode value from json, php

Tags: php, json

I need to decode the below json from a mobile app

```
Array
(
    [{"unm":"admin","pw”:”password”}] => 
)
```

and my php code is

```
$obj1 = print_r($_REQUEST, true); //get $_request variable data(responce of login) data as it is
foreach($obj1 as $key => $value)
{
    $obj2 = $key; //get first key
}
$obj3 = json_decode($obj2); //decode json data to obj3

$mob_user_name = $obj2['unm']; //getting json username field value
$mob_user_password = $obj2['pw']; //getting json password field value
```

Comment: You just confused me, in which lang you facing issue php or ios??

Comment: explain in brief ...?

Comment: That JSON is coming from a ios app  and i want to decode it in php @ dahiya_boy

Comment: please help me to decode this json in php @ramyr3my

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will fix your issue,
**Note:** content is nothing but which you have received from iOS app

> content = Array (
>       [{"unm":"admin","pw”:”password”}] =>  )

parse that in `php`

```
$json = json_decode($content, true);
print json[0]['unm']; /* prints the username */
print json[0]['pw']; /* prints the password */
```

Answer (score 0):

`{"unm":"admin","pw”:”password”}` is an object, and `json_decode()` will by default build it as so.

```
$obj = json_decode('{"unm":"admin","pw”:”password”}');
echo $obj->unm;
echo $obj->pw;
```

If for some reason you want it to be converted to an associative array, set the second parameter of `json_decode()` to `true` as specified in [the manual](http://www.php.net/json_decode).

```
$arr = json_decode('{"unm":"admin","pw”:”password”}', true);
echo $arr['unm'];
echo $arr['pw'];
```